# Asp.net Core get remote IP of client always returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core

My environment:
Ubuntu 18.04, Asp.net Core 2.1, Nginx

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) tutorial.
I added this code in Startup.cs:

```cs
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

I configure my Nginx configuration:

```
listen *:443 ssl http2;

location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto-Version $http2;
        client_max_body_size 32m;
        keepalive_timeout 200;
        send_timeout 20;
        client_body_timeout 50;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

I get the remote IP by:

```
var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```

but it always returns 127.0.0.1 from any IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally had to get header value manually. It was due to the cloud setting. Maybe this will help you.

```cs
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out var forwardedIps))
    senderIpv4 = forwardedIps.First();
```

Comment: how ```var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();``` it return 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in your nginx configuration.

Comment: i added, and restart nginx, i access by my phone but the console  still print out 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Specify reverse proxy Ip or just clear.

```
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
    ...
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1